# Only keep one version for each file and delete others

Tags: linux, unix, search

I have list of n files and some of the files are duplicate (Only differ by time stamp).  How can I keep only 1 copy and delete others?

File format - **x_y_z_timestamp.tgz**,  **x1_y1_z1_timestamp.tgz** ...  **xn_yn_zn_timestamp.tgz**

e.g.

1. x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz
2. x_y_z_20150113114533.tgz
3. x1_y1_z1_20150113060314.tgz
4. x1_y1_z1_20150113114533.tgz
5. x2_y2_z2_20150113060314.tgz
6. x2_y2_z2_20150113114533.tgz

Outcome -

1. x_y_z_20150113114533.tgz
2. x1_y1_z1_20150113114533.tgz
3. x2_y2_z2_20150113114533.tgz

Comment: Just to clear - It's not one file but I have others also like - x1_y1_z1_timestamp.tgz, x2_y2_z2_timestamp.tgz, x3_y3_z3_timestamp.tgz and each of the file has multiple versions (differ by timestamp only) .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`mv x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz copy_x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz;` `rm x_y_z*;`  `mv copy_x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz`

Explanation:

```
  1. mv x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz copy_x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz
```

copies the one you dont not want to delete into d/t file with filename that dont match the pattern x_y_z.

2. `rm x_y_z*;`
   remove all files that start with name pattern `x_y_z*;`
3. `mv copy_x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz x_y_z_20150113060314.tgz`
   rename the file you want to retain into its orginal name

Answer (score 0):

List them by their prefix:

```
ls x_y_z_* > test
```

sort the result by reverse order:

```
sort -r test > test.sorted
```

remove all files except the first one:

```
rm `tail +2 test.sorted`
```

Of course you can combine everything into a single command.